# mice package in RSTudio: Plot won't work for certain data

Tags: r, plot, imputation, r-mice

I am having trouble plotting convergence of an imputation with a mids object. I don't think I can create a reproducible example, because this problem only shows up with one (very large) data set.

The code I'm trying to run is the following:

```
plot(imp,y=c("variable1","variable2"))
```

The imputations ran successfully - I can produce summaries of variables for all 40 imputations, I can run a linear model, I can grab a complete data set from the mids object with complete(). I just can't get this one command to work, and it's necessary for validating my imputation.

Rather than throwing an error code, it draws a blank plot. Interestingly, the y-axes of the plot are labeled such that it clearly is using the data from the imputations - the means and SDs are on the y-axes, and they're in the range they should be.

I could use suggestions for where to troubleshoot. Let me know any more information I can add that would be helpful.

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit, RStudio 1.0.136, and R 3.3.3.

Thanks in advance!

[This is what the plot looks like with one data set of mine. With the problem one, it draws the axes (slightly different ranges), with no data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6n8ty.jpg)

Comment: Does the plot code throw an error?

Comment: Oh - nope, lemme edit to explain better... it draws a blank plot.

Comment: Perhaps if your data is very large it is taking a long time to do the calculations for the plot - i see this sometimes when plotting results from mcmc models. Have you tried waiting for some time? Have you tried monitoring your ram?

Comment: I've waited quite some time. I just ran it while watching the lil performance tab in Task Manager (can you tell I'm not the most computery of people?), and the CPU usage ticked up for a second, nothing else really changed. The other data set is still pretty large, and it plots in under a second.

Comment: I think I may have solved it. I wish I knew *why*. I made some changes to the predictor matrix - one part of that code wasn't written right. What I don't get is that bit of code was only specifying some variables to not be predicted - why should that matter? I ran 3 iterations and it plotted correctly, so now I'm running 17 more and I'll know tomorrow if it works.

Comment: Okay - this solved it. I correctly changed some of my predictor-only variables to not be predicted by the imputation, and it runs now. I don't know why! I am just glad it works.